# how to compare the empty bytelist in java

Tags: java, list

I need to check whether the list of bytes is empty or not? 
List b = Byte;
Following chuck of code is correct

```
    if(b == "[]")
    {
    SOP("empty")
    }
```

Comment: ...I don't see a question, unless you meant to put a question mark there and just forgot.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct if any satisfies your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isEmpty()`. You're currently comparing the `List` b to a `String` `[]` rather than checking if the `List` is empty.

```
if (b.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Empty");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are checking if a List is identical to a String. Maybe this will help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      byte[] b = new byte[]{};
      ArrayList<Byte> b2 = new ArrayList<Byte>();

      if (b.length == 0) {
          System.out.println("b is empty");
      }
      if (b2.isEmpty()) {
          System.out.println("b2 is empty");
      }
  }
}
```